# apache server can't start anymore

Tags: apache, mamp

with latest version of MAMPpro (3.3) I set PHP version for host from 5.3.29(standard) to 5.4.42. When MAMP asks for restart servers message appears that MAMP can't stop Apache. Hard stop of Apache is possible and proceeded.

Apache error log:

```
[Sat Jun 20 11:33:06 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Jun 20 11:33:06 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Jun 20 11:33:06 2015] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 52324)
[Sat Jun 20 11:33:06 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zd mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jun 20 11:44:30 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

From this point on it is not possible to start Apache again.
No further log entries.

When changing back PHP version to 5.3.29 everything works fine again.
Same problem appears in MAMP Pro version before (3.2.1)

Any solution for it?

OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
MAMP pro 3.3

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I found out that what was preventing my MAMP Pro from restarting properly/my APACHE server from initializing, was because my localhost was no longer configured properly. I went back into my regular MAMP, went through the preferences steps again, re-installed Wordpress onto my localhost in MAMP Pro, and then my APACHE re-initialized properly. Whenever you have this problem, it most probably is because there is something with your localhost, which is associated with your original regular MAMP installation. MAMP Pro won't function properly unless you have a proper install of "localhost". Hope this helps!